# How come I can't access AWS instance using Private DNS Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-vpc

I set up an AWS instance in my VPC with a private IP address -- no public IP address.  This is going to be my MongoDB instance and will only be accessed by other servers within the VPC.  I established a successful VPN connection and can SSH using Putty to the instance using the private IP address -  "10.0.0.95".  So far, so good.  I noticed that the private IP address also has a Private DNS - "ip-10-0-0-95.internal".  I tried using the Private DNS to access the instance through the VPN but got this Putty error "Unable to open connection to ip-10-0-0-95.ec2.internal.  Host does not exist".  Clearly, I can use the 10.0.0.95 IP address but was surprised that the private DNS name did not work.  How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable the DNS resolution for your VPC, or you won't be able to resolve internal DNS names.

To use private hosted zones, you must set the following Amazon VPC settings to true:

- enableDnsHostnames
- enableDnsSupport

Steps to enable DNS resolution:

- Open the Amazon VPC console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/.
- In the navigation pane, choose Your VPC.
- Select the VPC from the list, choose Actions and either Edit DNS Resolution or Edit DNS Hostnames (you should enable them)
- In the dialog box that opens, choose Yes, and Save.

For more info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-updating

Comment: I checked my VPC and both "DNS resolution" and "DNS hostnames" are both set to "yes".  I checked the documentation you pointed out and it seems that I am doing everything correct.  The private DNS name is a little different, "ip-10-0-0-95.ec2.internal".  Could it be that Putty does not like the url?  Maybe my VPN connection cannot resolve the DNS name?  I am using OpenVPN out of the box with their standard installation script.

Comment: Actually, as I think about it a little more, could it be that Putty and other desktop applications that I am running cannot resolve the DSN?  The DNS properly resolves the address with other instances running in the VPC.  It's just when I use the DNS with my desktop applications it does not work.  Your thoughts?